# How to run a function only once on collision?

Tags: java, function, events, audio, processing

If I check collisions between circles, for example

```
int x2 = 100;
int y2 = 100;  
int r2 = 10;
int count = 0;

boolean checkOnce = false;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  int x1 = mouseX;
  int y1 = mouseY;
  int r1 = 10;


  if (!checkOnce){
  checkCollision(x1, y1, r1);
  }


  drawCircle(x1, y1, r1);
  drawCircle(x2, y2, r2);

  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(count, width/2, height/2-30);
}

void checkCollision(int x, int y, int r) {


  if (dist(x, y, x2, y2) < (r + r2)) {
    checkOnce = true; 
    count++;
    //do something once;
  } else {
    count--;

  }


}

void drawCircle(int x, int y, int r) {
  ellipse(x, y, r*2, r*2);
}
```

This event gets triggered every frame while the two nodes are overlapping. How do I do something just once - for example play a sine wave, and then stop playing a sign wave once they are no longer overlapping?

Edit: I tried implementing the method suggested, but it stops checking for collisions after the first positive. If I have the boolean reset it just constantly loops as if there was no boolean at all.

Comment: You can check for collisions outside your `draw()`. That method should only be handling drawing operations.

Comment: Is that just best practice, or is there a performance advantage?  I guess I can see there being a significant difference if the objects were not moving each frame. Probably a good habit to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new variable. E.g. `boolean isAlreadyChecked = false`, and use it before `checkCollision`

```
if(!isAlreadyChecked) checkCollision(x1,y1,r1);
```

And in method

```
void checkCollision(int x1, int y1, int r1){
    isAlreadyChecked = true;
    if (dist(x1, y1, x2, y2) < (r1 + r2)){
    //do something once;
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, thanks. To avoid using another global variable, I have to pass the boolean value into the function and change it's condition to true inside of the conditional, right? Wouldn't this prevent checking a second time if a collision was detected? How do you check when no longer colliding (for example, start playing a sound on collision, stop playing when no longer collision).

Comment: It is a first step but not enough as the sound should be played while the collision checking is true and I suppose a minimum duration.

Comment: No. If I understood you well, there is no need to make a global variable - just `private boolean`, **and** you can change the state of this variable in some other piece of code. **But** if you want to access this var in some other class, you should implement `public boolean isAlreadyChecked(){ return isAlreadyChecked;}` and `public void setIsAlreadyChecked (boolean isAlreadyChecked){//....}`

Comment: @davidxxx, Yep, but this would be another kind of question. Right?

Comment: @zlakad  In a some way yes. But OP asks both at the same time :-)

Comment: @davidxxx haha... We cannot read famous **crystal ball**. Anyway, I wish the OP can catch some clue from this so-called answer. ;)

Comment: I edited my demo script with this suggestion (see above), however the main issue is that once it finds a collision it stops checking for collisions. I need to run some code once, but keep checking for collisions so I can toggle the state back and forth if that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense. Toggling `boolean` is up to you! Ask yourself: *when* I should let the `checkCollision` to actually run? Whenever this condition  becomes true, call `setIsAlreadyChecked(false)` - so your checking is available again. Reading your edited code, this 'condition' is true whenever the `count  <= 0`. Am I right?

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution that "works" although it may not be the best way to do it. Can you check my solution and see if I could improve it in some way?

Comment: If it works - it works. Leave this for now, you can always come back and re-implement your code (of course, if you are not satisfied). Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out a solution, although messy.

It requires two booleans. Set the booleans to the same state, and then modify them on collision. Run code if the two booleans do not match any longer and then set them to match. This will run code every time something changes, but still allow the function to be called every frame. >:)

For your viewing pleasure:

```
int x2 = 100;
int y2 = 100;  
int r2 = 10;
int count = 0;

boolean checkOnce = false;
boolean toggle = false;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  int x1 = mouseX;
  int y1 = mouseY;
  int r1 = 10;



  checkCollision(x1, y1, r1);


  println("bool", checkOnce);

  drawCircle(x1, y1, r1);
  drawCircle(x2, y2, r2);

  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(count, width/2, height/2-30);
}

void checkCollision(int x, int y, int r) {


  if (checkOnce != toggle) {
    Counter(checkOnce);
    toggle = checkOnce;
  }


  if (dist(x, y, x2, y2) < (r + r2)) {
    checkOnce = true;
    //do something once;
  } else {
    checkOnce = false;
  }
}

void drawCircle(int x, int y, int r) {
  ellipse(x, y, r*2, r*2);
}

void Counter(boolean Contact) {
  if (Contact) {

    count ++;
  } else {
    count --;
  }
}
```